# Rails 5 add link_to in mailer text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-email

I am using Mail-factory to sending email from my Rails 5 application. Here I need to include link which will take users to corresponding page.

The code which I have done in my controller is

```
url = "http://localhost:3000/sample_page"
mail = MailFactory.new()
        mail.to = ApplicationController.admin_user_email
        mail.from = "from_eail"
        mail.subject = subject
mail.text = "Hi, view_context.link_to(Test, url)"
```

But while receiving email, the content is like,

```
Hi <a href="link_here">Test</a>
```

But I need to show my link as like.

```
Hi [Test][1]
```

Please correct me if I were wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to the following

```
mail.text = "Hi, [#{view_context.link_to('Test', url)}]".html_safe
```

Comment: Now the content is like <a href="link">Test</a>. But i need to show only the Test with Link tag. Thanks

Comment: I am getting in my email with the HTML tag.

Comment: @KarthikMuthu Updated the answer try this one

Comment: Sorry still i am getting the same one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing in the URL as a variable, you should be able to just print it out like this:

`mail.text = "Hi [Test][#{url}]"`